# How to calculate Price/Earnings - Price/Sales - Price/Free Cash Flow for given stock

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I have few months of data for some company like `opening, high, low, closing, volume` .

As given at https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE%3ABME&ei=DSIeVtGMAYrvuATEsZfACA

How to calculate

`How to calculate Price/Earnings - Price/Sales - Price/Free Cash Flow` for given stock in % value.

Comment: You are aware that the linked instrument is a fund and not a stock I assume?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate you take the `Price` and divide it by the `Earnings`, or by the `Sales`, or by the `Free Cash Flow`.

Most of these calculations are done for you on a lot of finance sites if the data is available. Such sites as Yahoo Finance and Google Finance as well as my personal favorite: [Morningstar](http://morningstar.com)